# How to get iWork Suite for macOS Sierra?

Tags: macos, macos-sierra, iwork-pages

Where/How can I get the last version of pages that is supported for macOS Sierra.6?

The app store does not provide me with an option to download the last supported version.

It shows the following error message:
The app pages/numbers/keynote cannot be installed on [disk] because macOS version 10.13 or higher is required.

I've tried searching all the forums but couldn't find any thing hepful.

Comment: Where are you trying to download it from, 'search' or existing Purchases? Purchases should work - it should either say Download if there's a valid update, or Open if there isn't.

Comment: I just popped open the app store and typed "Pages" and it came up immediately. Are you saying it isn't there at all, or it won't give you the newest version?

Comment: At the moment I'm not really saying anything - I'm trying to get you to clarify *exactly* what you did & *exactly* what happened when you did it.

Comment: I tried to download pages, it said pages is supported only for macOS 10.13 and above, and it doesn't give me any option to download the last supported version

Comment: Then I'm guessing it only works if you're on the last OS your machine can support. No machine is 'stuck' at Sierra, High Sierra is your next 'sticking point', though if your Mac can take it, Mojave is better than other of the Sierras.

Comment: I've found sierra to be faster on my machine although it supports Mojave or even Catalina . So it would be a great if I could get pages working on this machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: I found the solution to this

Step 1: Download and install iWork 2009 trial from [here](http://appldnld.apple.com.edgesuite.net/content.info.apple.com/iWork/Trial/2Z693-6764.01022009.awq23/iWork09Trial.dmg).

Step 2: Go to App Store > Updates > Keynotes/Pages/Numbers (Maybe under the show incompatible updates section)

Step 3: Choose update on each of the app

Step 4: When the error message appears click on OK.

Step 5: It'll prompt with a option to install last compatible version, Done!

Comment: Wow, kudos! I didn't know that method still worked. I did it myself, maybe 5 years or more ago.

Comment: As of the time of this comment - this method worked, in that I was able to download an install iWork 2009, and use Numbers on my macOS 10.13.  I have yet to see an app update.  So far this satisfies my needs.

Comment: At least on High Sierra, I don't get any prompt to download the last compatible version. And I think I didn't get it on Sierra either.