# How to get iWork suite on macOS High Sierra?

Tags: mac, macos-highsierra, iwork-pages

I have seen one other question related to this, [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1470938/how-to-get-iwork-suite-for-macos-sierra).
However, this did not work for me. I recently got a MacBook Pro with macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 on it. I created my Apple ID, as this is the first time in a long time that I have had a Mac. Anyway, I started rooting around and installing my favorite apps etc., when I noticed that Pages is missing! I love the iWork suite. I tried to get it in the App Store, but it says that

> "You must have macOS 14.yadadada or higher to install this app".

I saw the aforementioned question, and tried the accepted answer. This was *so close* to working! It worked all the way up until right after I entered my Apple ID password. Then it said,

> "Pages can’t be installed on “Headquarters” because macOS version 10.14 or later is required. The application will be available from the Purchased page"

When I go "Purchased", I can see what looks like the new version, but when I open it through that tab it opens the 0.9 version. I also can't see it in the Applications folder. Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks.

-

Alternatively, if anyone knows a good Pages alternative (other than LibreOffice), I would love to hear it!

Comment: Is your machine stuck at High Sierra, no possibility to update? Specific model would help assess this.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes. The computer I got is an early 2011 13-inch MacBook Pro with a core i7. It it one year to old to get the Mojave Update.

Comment: if the apps [any version] were previously authorised to that Apple ID, it ought to just automatically offer you the last compatible version. Not at all sure why it isn't doing.

Comment: My old Apple ID was unrecoverable since I stopped using both the email and the phone it was registered to. I just created a new Apple ID @Tetsujin

Comment: Then your best bet may be to try recover the old ID. The start point is https://iforgot.apple.com but idk how far through that process you can get. The security questions might be your route.

Comment: @Tetsujin alright, thanks! Could you put your comments into an answer so I can mark this as solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comments:
I think the distinction is that the Apple ID must already have 'purchased' the software. After that, attempting to download it from an older macOS ought to present you with the opportunity to acquire the last version applicable to that OS.

The solution in this particular case might be to attempt to re-access an earlier Apple ID which already has all the iWork components in its purchase history.

Answer (score 0):

Alright. Tetsujin's answer worked great on another computer, but here is an alternative. I am not sure why or how this works, but whatever.

Use the link I mentioned in my question, and follow all the steps. (Note that you might have to "show unsupported apps" or something like that.)  It will still say that "You cannot update this app" or such. Restart your computer.

Go to the App Store. Search "pages", then hit the tiny "get" button. Then the "install" button. For whatever reason, this works but if you click on the pages icon to get more info it doesn't.

If you are willing to dive into the deep end, there is another choice. I do not "officially" recommend this, as it can be quite dangerous. Before trying this, make sure that you have backed up your computer several times with time machine, and that you have a High Sierra installation USB just in case. Another note. If anything goes wrong you are violating Apple's EULA, which will most likely void your warranty. However, if your computer really *cannot* update, it is probably not under warranty anyway. Mine just has the apple support covered (which I thought was free anyway), so there was no danger in that for me, and probably not for any of you. Alright. Go to [this site](http://dosdude1.com/mojave/). Follow the directions there, which seemed to be pretty self-explanatory. After following the instructions, which personally took ~30 mins, you should boot into a fully functional version of macOS Mojave! As you can see below, getting the "About My Mac" window show that I am running macOS Mojave on an unsupported Mac!

[image: mojavepic]